# Automatically filling cells in Excel row by taking input from another cell in row

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create VBA code so that when I enter "free" in a cell K6 other cells in that row such as E6, F6, G6, H6 should automatically fill with "NA" and it should continue for subsequent rows like K7, K8 and so on.

The below code is entering the values in all the rows except the one selected.

```vb
Dim zng As Range 
Set zng Range ("K6:K100") 
If Not Intersect (Target, zng) Is Nothing Then 
    Application.EnableEvents False 
    If Target.Value = "Free" Then 
         Range ("E6:E100") "NA" 
    End If 
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing `=` signs ... here: `Set zng = Range ("K6:K100")` and here: `Application.EnableEvents = False` and here: `Range ("E6:E100") = "NA"`

Comment: Missed it while typing here, but now the problem is with this code when i enter free in cell K6 VBA shou enter NA only in cell E6 but instead it is entering in all the cells from E6 to E100 kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method you can use to update your cells:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim zng As Range, c As Range
    Set zng = Intersect(Target, Range("K6:K100"))
    If Not zng Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            For Each c In zng
               If c.Value = "Free" Then
                    c.EntireRow.Range("E1:I1,L1") = "NA"
               End If
            Next
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'll have to remember the range use on an entire row but that poor "I1" being separated from the group is quite sad :/

Comment: Aargh! You're right, that was silly of me. I'll amend.

Answer (score 0):

Last edit from the comments, this will now put NA in the range E:I,L if there's free in K6 to last row / It will empty it if there's something else than "free" and move its entire row to the last row:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim zng As Range, ccell, dRng As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = Me.Range("K" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set zng = Me.Range("K6:K" & lRow)

    If Not Intersect(Target, zng) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each ccell In Intersect(Target, zng).Cells
            Set dRng = Me.Range("E" & ccell.Row & ":J" & ccell.Row & ",L" & ccell.Row)
            If UCase(ccell.Value) = "FREE" Then 'UCase since you spoke of "free" and "Free"
                dRng.Value = "NA"
                ccell.EntireRow.Cut
                Me.Range("A" & lRow + 1).EntireRow.Insert
            Else
                dRng.Value = ""
            End If
        Next ccell
        Application.EnableEvents = True 'Don't forget to set this back to true
    End If
End Sub
```

This should change the range E:I & L (small edit on the range from comment) on the same row as the target cell (adjust the range if needed):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim zng As Range, dRng As Range
    Set zng = Me.Range("K6:K100")
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 'If you're only doing one cell at a time
    If Not Intersect(Target, zng) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Set dRng = Me.Range("E" & Target.Row & ":I" & Target.Row & ",L" & Target.Row)
        If UCase(Target.Value) = "FREE" Then 'UCase since you spoke of "free" and "Free"
            dRng.Value = "NA"
        Else
            dRng.Value = ""
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True 'Don't forget to set this back to true
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to change multiple cells at once:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim zng As Range, ccell, dRng As Range
    Set zng = Me.Range("K6:K100")

    If Not Intersect(Target, zng) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each ccell In Intersect(Target, zng).Cells
            Set dRng = Me.Range("E" & ccell.Row & ":J" & ccell.Row & ",L" & ccell.Row)
            If UCase(ccell.Value) = "FREE" Then 'UCase since you spoke of "free" and "Free"
                dRng.Value = "NA"
            Else
                dRng.Value = ""
            End If
        Next ccell
        Application.EnableEvents = True 'Don't forget to set this back to true
    End If
End Sub
```

Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: This works but i want to change values "NA" in cells E, F, G, H, I & L could you please help in in editing the above code accordingly?

Comment: Edit should do E:I & L. Note that you can't just keep adding ranges to it, that'd need some more tweaking then but right now, this works.

Comment: Thank yo so much works perfectly

Comment: You're welcome, hope you learned something from it :)

Comment: One last thing required, in case the value "Free" is removed from cell "K" values "NA" is not getting removed from other mentioned cells in that particular row please help

Comment: Should it just become empty?

Comment: Yes it should be empty if "Free" is deleted or something else is entered

Comment: If *anything* else is added than "free", the cells will be emptied now. Note that I used another range variable now to avoid clutter.

Comment: Sorry for troubling this is the last thing I want to achieve, suppose if I enter "Free" in one of the cells in column "K" is it possible to automatically send the entire row to last in that particular sheet? This would be a great help if u could solve it to me.

Comment: Formulate your question fully next time instead of piling on requirements afterwards. It's not clear to the people checking the answers nor is it for other people answering like CLR. Last edit is on the top of my answer.